# CSS Print Issue in iOS devices

Tags: css, printing

Desktop (windows and Mac are showing correct print preview but iOS devices are not showing full width and some blank space above too.

Problem is I don't have any option to debug this in Browserstack. I can debug only in desktop rendering option.

This is my code:

```css
@media print {
  body {
    -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100% !important;
    padding-right: 0 !important;
    padding-left: 0 !important;
    margin: 0 auto !important;
  }
  .cssr-print {
    display: block;
    visibility: visible;
    margin-top: 0px !important;
    margin-bottom: 0px !important;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: @white;
    padding: 50px 0 0;
    max-width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='cssr-print'>
  .....
</div>
```

[image: iPhone]

[image: Desktop]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changed

```css
position: fixed;
```

to

```css
position: absolute;
```